# Chrome Extension Manifest V3 Loading Remote JSON Configuration

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on transitioning from Manifest 2 to Manifest 3 and in Manifest 2 I was pulling in a remotely hosted json file and using that to enable and disable settings. It has to be dynamic otherwise I'd include it in the extension itself. Looking at the migration guide from Google I see this:

In Chrome Extension manifest v3 remotely hosted code is no longer allowed. The migration documentation has two solutions.

> Configuration-driven features and logic—In this approach, your
> extension loads a remote configuration (for example a JSON file) at
> runtime and caches the configuration locally. The extension then uses
> this cached configuration to decide which features to enable.
>
> Externalize logic with a remote service—Consider migrating application
> logic from the extension to a remote web service that your extension
> can call. (Essentially a form of message passing.) This provides you
> the ability to keep code private and change the code on demand while
> avoiding the extra overhead of resubmitting to the Chrome Web Store.

The first option sounds like what I am looking for, but I can't find any documentation on to achieve this approach. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

For reference this is how I was previously pulling it into the extension:

```
async function readJson() {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/config.json');
  console.log(response.ok);
  if (!response.ok) {
    const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;

    throw new Error(message);
  }

  const json = await response.json();

  return json;
  
}
```

Comment: You were already doing it, so there's no need to change anything.

Comment: Hi wOxxOm, 

I am now getting a CORS error in the console trying to access the file, here is what I am seeing when I point it at my local server:

popup.html:1 Access to fetch at 'http://10.211.55.5:8000/storage/config.json' from origin 'chrome-extension://pfcchakjdncfgpiikabjdebpcollfmgn' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: It should work so there's a problem in your code. Show an [MCVE](/help/mcve) that includes your manifest.json, its host permissions, where the code runs, how that file is loaded.

Comment: wOxxOm, you couldn't be more right, totally spaced when I switched to testing on my local my headers were incorrect so it couldnt pull it in. Thanks for helping me out!